# trying to set functionality of menu items in menu bar with wxpython

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

here's my code for setting up the menu items in menu-bar with their functionally. but I don't know why but its just not working, I mean when I set open's functionally it worked but when I'm setting others it didn't and nor it is taking the history menu and help menu. presently I have commented the history and help code but when I remove the commas it gives error. (I'm not too good with python I have just started so need some help, in getting where I'm wrong.)

```
import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MenuFrame(None, title="Menus and MenuBars")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()

        return True

ID_READ_ONLY = wx.NewId()

class MenuFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MenuFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Attributes
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.txtctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,
                                   style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        # Layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.txtctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.CreateStatusBar() # For output display

        # Setup the Menu
        menub = wx.MenuBar()

        # File Menu
        filem = wx.Menu()
        filem.Append(wx.ID_NEW, "New\tCtrl+N")
        filem.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "Open\tCtrl+O")
        filem.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, "Save\tCtrl+S")
        filem.Append(wx.ID_SAVEAS, "Save_As\tCtrl+Shift+S")
        menub.Append(filem, "&File")

        # Edit Menu
        editm = wx.Menu()
        editm.Append(wx.ID_UNDO, "Undo\tCtrl+Z")
        editm.Append(wx.ID_REDO, "Redo\tCtrl+Shift+Z")
        editm.Append(wx.ID_COPY, "Copy\tCtrl+C")
        editm.Append(wx.ID_CUT, "Cut\tCtrl+X")
        editm.Append(wx.ID_PASTE, "Paste\tCtrl+V")
        editm.Append(wx.ID_SELECTALL, "SelectAll\tCtrl+A")
        editm.AppendSeparator()
        editm.Append(ID_READ_ONLY, "Read Only",
                     kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        menub.Append(editm, "E&dit")

        """# History Menu
        historym = wx.Menu()
        historym.Append(wx.ID_RECENT, "Recent\tCtrl+N")
        menub.Append(historym, "&History")

        # Help Menu
        helpm = wx.Menu()
        helpm.Append(wx.ID_HINT, "Hint")
        helpm.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "About")
        menub.Append(helpm, "&Help")"""

        self.SetMenuBar(menub)

        # Event Handlers
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnMenu)

    def OnMenu(self, event):
        """Handle menu clicks"""
        evt_id = event.GetId()
        actions = { wx.ID_COPY  : self.txtctrl.Copy,
                    wx.ID_CUT   : self.txtctrl.Cut,
                    wx.ID_PASTE : self.txtctrl.Paste }
        action = actions.get(evt_id, None)
        if action:
            action()
        elif evt_id == ID_READ_ONLY:
            # Toggle enabled state
            self.txtctrl.Enable(not self.txtctrl.Enabled)
        elif evt_id == wx.ID_OPEN:
            dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open File", style=wx.FD_OPEN)
            if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                fname = dlg.GetPath()
                handle = open(fname, 'r')
                self.txtctrl.SetValue(handle.read())
                handle.close()
        else:
            event.Skip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `history` and `help` menus, is that the Id's that you are using do not exist i.e. `ID_RECENT` and `ID_HINT`, so use something else or assign your own Id's.
The `selectall` function was not assigned.
Note, that the `cut` and `copy` functions require that you have selected something.
You haven't written any code for the `Save` or `Saveas` functions.
The `undo` and `redo` functions do not seem to function in a standard `wx.TextCtrl`, so you could use a `StyledTextCtrl` instead.
Hopefully, the code below will move you on a bit.
(It's for wxpython Phoenix and python3 on Linux)

```
import wx
import wx.stc
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MenuFrame(None, title="Menus and MenuBars")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()

        return True

ID_READ_ONLY = wx.NewId()

class MenuFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MenuFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Attributes
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.txtctrl = wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl(self.panel,
                                   style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        # Layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.txtctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.CreateStatusBar() # For output display

        # Setup the Menu
        menub = wx.MenuBar()

        # File Menu
        filem = wx.Menu()
        filem.Append(wx.ID_NEW, "New\tCtrl+N")
        filem.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "Open\tCtrl+O")
        filem.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, "Save\tCtrl+S")
        filem.Append(wx.ID_SAVEAS, "Save_As\tCtrl+Shift+S")
        menub.Append(filem, "&File")

        # Edit Menu
        editm = wx.Menu()
        editm.Append(wx.ID_UNDO, "Undo\tCtrl+Z")
        editm.Append(wx.ID_REDO, "Redo\tCtrl+Shift+Z")
        editm.Append(wx.ID_COPY, "Copy\tCtrl+C")
        editm.Append(wx.ID_CUT, "Cut\tCtrl+X")
        editm.Append(wx.ID_PASTE, "Paste\tCtrl+V")
        editm.Append(wx.ID_SELECTALL, "SelectAll\tCtrl+A")
        editm.AppendSeparator()
        editm.Append(ID_READ_ONLY, "Read Only",
                     kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        menub.Append(editm, "E&dit")

        # History Menu
        historym = wx.Menu()
        historym.Append(wx.ID_PREVIEW, "Recent\tCtrl+N")
        menub.Append(historym, "&History")

        # Help Menu
        helpm = wx.Menu()
        helpm.Append(wx.ID_HELP_INDEX, "Hint")
        helpm.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "About")
        menub.Append(helpm, "&Help")

        self.SetMenuBar(menub)

        # Event Handlers
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnMenu)

    def OnMenu(self, event):
        """Handle menu clicks"""
        evt_id = event.GetId()
        actions = { wx.ID_COPY  : self.txtctrl.Copy,
                    wx.ID_CUT   : self.txtctrl.Cut,
                    wx.ID_PASTE : self.txtctrl.Paste,
                    wx.ID_UNDO : self.txtctrl.Undo,
                    wx.ID_REDO : self.txtctrl.Redo,
                    wx.ID_SELECTALL : self.txtctrl.SelectAll}
        action = actions.get(evt_id, None)
        if action:
            action()
        elif evt_id == ID_READ_ONLY:
            # Toggle enabled state
            self.txtctrl.Enable(not self.txtctrl.Enabled)
        elif evt_id == wx.ID_OPEN:
            dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open File", style=wx.FD_OPEN)
            if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                fname = dlg.GetPath()
                handle = open(fname, 'r')
                self.txtctrl.SetValue(handle.read())
                handle.close()
        else:
            event.Skip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: @monikarazdan Perhaps, any accept or vote up is in order.